# Saving fish from ick/ich

Tags: fish

I have ciclids and guppies and African frogs in a 30gal tank. I'm new to this and didn't realize I was supposed to quarantine new fish before introducing them. I introduced a ciclid with ich without knowing it. Now my other ciclids have ich.

I've read that a combination of ick medicine and heat (84F) can solve ich.

1) Can these fish and frogs survive 84F? In general, which common fish can't survive 84F? I assume I just heat it up slowly.

2) Should I treat the 30gal tank, or transfer the fish to a smaller tank (filled with water from the larger tank) and treat them there?

3) In future during quarantine before introducing a new fish, do I just monitor it? Or can I put a small chemical cocktail (like some ich medicine) in the water for a few days to kill any bugs? If the latter, what chemicals/medicines do you recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :) I've marked your question as a duplicate of one that has already been asked and answered. The answer to that question contains detailed instructions about how to treat ich. I've also [answered a question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/17882/6826) about medicating a tank with mixed fish in it.